# Enviar branch específico com Git para Github

Tags: git, github, deploy, gulp

como eu consigo enviar um branch específico para o Github através do Git?

Estou criando um projeto para aprender a utilizar o Gulp e seus plugins, e nele criei uma pasta com o código fonte, chamada `src` e uma pasta contendo os arquivos minificados, folhas CSS processados e etc., chamada `build`. Tentei criar um branch no Git chamado `deploy` e adicionar apenas os arquivos de build nesse branch e então fazer o `pull` para o repositório, mas não consigo mandar apenas esta pasta.

Nos vários testes que fiz às vezes vai todo o projeto, com a pasta `src`, às vezes é criado um outro branch remoto no repositório..

Vocês tem alguma dica de organização desse tipo, para projetos com task runners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O git não foi feito para ser utilizado como você está pensando. Se você que armazenar a build gerada pelo seu código faz mais sentido ter um outro repositório apenas para a build. Ou manter uma subpasta chamada build que sempre seja versionado junto com o código que gerou aquela build.

Na minha opinião versionar a build não faz muito sentido. Pois você sempre pode gerar a build a partir de um dado commit do git. Eu colocaria minha build apenas como um arquivo a ser publicado no servidor no meio do pipeline de deploy.

Comment: Como funciona esse pipeline de deploy? O próprio Gulp tem uma função de deploy, ou algum plugin projetado pra isso? Talvez seja exatamente isso a solução. O motivo de ter incluído a build ao versionamento foi justamente não saber como fazer o deploy posteriormente (sem FTP ou afins).

Comment: Aí vai depender de como você quer fazer o deploy, mas sim o gulp possui muitas bibliotecas para ajudar no deploy. Por exemplo se você quer enviar só os arquivos estáticos para o AWS vc tem um plugin de gulp que se comunica com o S3 e armazena tudo lá. Caso você tenha máquinas virtuais que rodam na nuvem, você pode enviar um arquivo zipado com sua build para algum storage na nuvem e fazer sua máquina virtual baixar esse arquivo. Outra opção seria utilizar o gulp para enviar diretamente para sua VM por ftp. Existe inumeras opções nesse ponto do deploy.

Comment: Vou pesquisar a respeito. Obrigado pelas direções!

Answer (score 1):

Quando você já tem o seu repositório vazio no github, você pode pegar a referencia de duas maneiras.

- Clonando o repositório

Desse modo, você usa a url do para clonar(baixar) o repositório para o seu computador usando o git clone.

```
$ git clone http://github.com/<user>/<repository>.git <nome da pasta>
```

---

- Iniciando um projeto git(creio que seja o seu caso)

Você deve inciar a pasta do seu projeto e referenciar ao seu repositório no github.

```
$ cd <pasta do projeto>
$ git init
$ git add <pasta que deseja adicionar ao repositório>
$ git commit -m "comentário"
$ git remote add origin http://github.com/<user>/<repository>.git
$ git push origin master
```

Caso não aceite o `git push origin master`, pode ser pelo caso de já existir arquivos no seu repositório. Então deverá ser feito o pull antes de enviar os novos arquivos.

```
$ git pull origin master
$ git push origin master
```

Com o segundo método, você pode escolher quais arquivos e pastas deseja enviar para o seu repositório no github.

Comment: Mas dessa forma o meu branch master irá ser pushado, certo? Dessa forma também vai a pasta `src`. Tem como mandar por exemplo apenas um outro branch criado e os arquivos que foram adicionados nele? Um branch orfão `deploy` por exemplo, apenas com os arquivos de build?